# replace module failed goland

Tags: go, goland

I'm having a hard time replacing a module within go.

I was trying to clean the cache, `go get <PackageName>`, explicitly telling the compiler to change the module path etc..

`replace github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws => github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws v1.2.3`

I was digging online but non of the solutions I saw helped me.

```
GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\omer\go #gosetup
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" mod tidy #gosetup
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/resource
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/terraform
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/diag
go: finding module for package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema
go: finding module for package github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/validation
go: found github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror in github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror v1.1.1
go: found github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/diag in github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.8.0
go: found github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema in github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.8.0
go: found github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/validation in github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.8.0
go: found github.com/ravendb/ravendb-go-client in github.com/ravendb/ravendb-go-client v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: found github.com/ravendb/ravendb-go-client/serverwide/operations in github.com/ravendb/ravendb-go-client v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: found github.com/ravendb/terraform-provider-ravendb/utils in github.com/ravendb/terraform-provider-ravendb v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: found golang.org/x/crypto/ssh in golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20210921155107-089bfa567519
go: found github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/resource in github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.8.0
go: found github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/terraform in github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.8.0
go: found github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws in github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws v1.60.0
go: terraform-provider-ravendb/ravendb tested by
    terraform-provider-ravendb/ravendb.test imports
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws@v1.60.0: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws
            but was required as: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws
```

Comment: There is no module called `github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws`, it only declared itself as `github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws`. Besides the fact that this project is not intended to be imported, what problem are you trying to solve with the replace directive here?

Comment: How can I identify that the package does not exists ? I checked in MongoDB provider and I saw they were using `github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/aws ` Also, I can't seem to delete the packages nor to run go mod init/tidy to delete the error for start

Comment: I can only try and guess what you are doing without a [mre], but you can see what the `terraform-provider-aws` module calls itself in the `go.mod` file. I'm not sure what you are doing with that replace directive, but there's a good change that because the project is not intended to be imported, and the github and module paths don't match, you are not going to be able to work with that package or get reasonably recent tags at all.